# Dealing with CSS Conflicts in a Third-Party Integration Widget - ReactJS - Tailwindcss

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm currently developing a web widget that's meant to be integrated into third-party websites.

The widget uses **`tailwindcss`** with prefixed class names and includes a CSS reset with preflight. However, I'm encountering a CSS conflict issue when the third-party websites have styles that affect the default HTML tags used by my widget.

For example, some third-party websites have CSS code like:

```
label { display: inline-block; }
```

or

```
input[type="file"] {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This conflicts with my widget's default styling, causing the widget's interface to break.

I want to ask some best practices I can follow for this case.

Any advice or suggestions on how to handle CSS conflicts in this scenario would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to make a cross framework or multi-project component. i suggest you to give web-components a try. where you can scope your style.

You can use Lit js for this case for easy development. as css conflicts are inevitable. as you are using tailwind css which does have very low specificity. an can be easily overridden.

Comment: - Thank you for your answer and I cannot do as you suggest because change from tailwind-css to any other CSS framework will take a lot of effort for our team. 
- It's not all about priority. There is some HTML tags  I will not add css and let them as default but the third-party websites using my widget have set css for those default tag which make my code break.

Comment: Lit is not a css framework you can use tailwinds no one is stopping you. it allows you to make web-components of your own naming. and you can still receive props or arguments from user like you already do with any normal html tags. as you can accept props you can give your users option to style them  using props in a controlled manner while keeping your styles untouched.

Comment: and lit is framework agnostic so your component can work with any framework